# Access Other Application AD in Web api from other application

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to access web Api which is having Client 1 AD Auth and other app is Using different Client 2 AD

In Portal Have user_impersonation is set for both client

But JWT token is not getting validate with that

Comment: It would be helpful in clarifying your question if you could add some code snippets showing what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please check carefully the token as the problem with validation may be related to having the wrong aud in the token. To verify token, you can use https://jwt.io/